# In SQL Server Management Studio, how do I set up the keyboard shortcuts so that ctrl+w closes an XML window?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssms, ssms-2012

In SQL Server Management Studio, how do I set up the keyboard shortcuts so that ctrl+w closes an XML window?

I know how to do this for a regular query window.  [Here's how](https://www.am2.co/2017/01/close-ssms-tab/).  But some of my tables have XML columns, and when I click on an XML value, it opens a window that doesn't respond to my custom ctrl+w command.  Is this possible to set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could set up <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut to close text tabs (like XML preview).

First you have to remove existing shortcut `CTRL+W` which highlights current word (click Remove):

[image]

Then add new shortcut (click Assign):

[image]

To be sure you could restart SSMS.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this shortcut doesn't work with XML documents.  I linked to this shortcut in my question.

Comment: @user2023861 Strange. In my instance it works perfectly. Maybe because I have ssms v17

Comment: @user2023861 Please check if something else is set in "shortcut currently used by" like in second printscreen. Maybe something else intercepts shortcut.

Comment: that did it. Thanks!